# "Sniff" SQL queries being sent out from my computer

Tags: sql-server, string

I'm a student working on pulling certain information from an SQL server here at work. I don't have sysadmin privileges and my attempts at receiving them have not been met with success. It's a big company and the bureaucracy surrounding these things is nothing short of ridiculous, so that isn't an option.

I want to run a query that is already being executed by one of the programs on this computer, but with slightly different parameters (joining a few more tables, etc). The database is vast and incredibly complicated, and I've therefore been unable to understand how this program gets the information it does.

So my question is this: is there any way to monitor the queries being sent from my computer, specifically the query text? It would be tremendously helpful and save me time, energy, and a hell of a lot of red tape.

(I recognize this may seem like a stupid question or that I'm asking the impossible - if it can't be done it's no big deal - I can get by without it. It'd be nice, though.)

Comment: If you are not being granted access then expect to get yourself into a whole heap of trouble if you are trying to access information without authorisation - and don't expect help here

Comment: On the assumption that you are not being malicious,  you could try[Wireshark](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/23059/can-wireshark-be-used-to-seeshow-sql-db2-statementsexpression) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2436/what-does-my-sql-server-data-look-like-over-the-wire/) looks to be good. Ask a supervisor about permission to install this. With great power comes great responsibility! :-)

Comment: @Vérace - no I'm not trying to be malicious, it's just impossible to get the developer of the program I'm talking about to cooperate with me because he's a full-time engineer and I'm just a "lowly" student trying to write a few simple tools :(

Comment: Without being disrespectful to you, the fact is yes you are a student and not working at the level where such elevated access rights (probably to production systems) is safe, especially when you don't actually need it for what you want to do. The fact you cite bureaucracy as the basis for that decision is frankly the reason why your request hasn't been granted. I would type up an email to whomever it may concern, not asking for any specific rights, but asking instead for help solving the problem at hand. Push it through your supervisor if needs must.

Answer (score 6):

You do not require sysadmin privileges for what you want. You can use SQL Profiler and for that the required privilege is `ALTER TRACE`, see [Permissions Required to Run SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187611.aspx). Ask for the minimum required permission and perhaps will be granted.

Answer (score 3):

As Remus Rusanu says you do not need `SysAdmin` rights to run a trace, you need `ALTER TRACE` permissions.

I don't know anything about your company, but as a DBA in a large public organisation I have much experience of users asking for `SysAdmin` rights because they want to run a trace to 'figure out what a query is doing...'

When asked that question, I don't flatly say no, I explain why it isn't a good idea to run client side traces and to put SQL Profiler in the hands of the users. Sure one of the reasons is long traces can have a performance impact on production systems, which is of course a worry, but there's also the setting up of the profile and the interpreting of the output - you don't want any help with that? The fact that you may have never used Profiler before or understand its complexities and consequences would fill me with worry.

I always engage in a bit of dialogue about why server side traces or extended events is potentially better. I ask why they're investigating what the query is doing - maybe I, or one of my team, can help without a trace.

It works both ways though, I am wondering if you have fully explained what you want to do to your DBA's or IT Management Team. I think sometimes when people go guns-blazing asking for SysAdmin rights without effectively engaging in a bit of dialogue you end up with closed doors and brick walls (bureaucracy as you call it) rather than collaboration, co-operation and learning experiences.

You may have done this of course, and your IT team may just be stubborn - but this is just my two cents.

Plus, if I found out that third-party tools were being used in isolation without the authority to do so I would put that user in breach of our acceptable use policy and report it - so please be careful if you're going down that road. Doesn't matter what company you work for - one team, remember?